# Is there a name for theorem ,$x^a - 1 \equiv 0 \mod {(x -1)}$, and how is my proof?

Tags: modular-arithmetic

I came to realise after practising some modular arithmetic that:

$x$, $(x-1)$$\space$ are$\space$ co-prime$ \space$ $\wedge$ $\space$ $x$, $(x-1)$ $\in$ $\mathbb{N}$ $\implies$ $x^\alpha \mod (x-1)$ = $1$ : $\forall$ $\alpha$ $\in$ $\mathbb{N}$

What is the name for this theorem, and who first proved it?

If someone could review the rigor of my proof that would be helpful:

Let the *hypothesis* be denoted as '$p$': $x$, $(x-1)$$\space$ are$\space$ co-prime$ \space$ $\wedge$ $\space$ $x$, $(x-1)$ $\in$ $\mathbb{N}$

Let the *conclusion* be denoted as '$q$': $\forall$ $\alpha$ $\in$ $\mathbb{N}$, $\space$ $x^\alpha \mod (x-1)$ = $1$

$p$ $\implies$ $q$.

*Direct Proof:*

Take the theorem $(A)^n \mod m$ $\iff$ $(A\mod m)^n \mod m$ : $A$ $\in$ $\mathbb{Z}$,$\space$ $n$, $m$ $\in$ $\mathbb{N}$: $m$ $\neq$ $0$

Then, given $p$, if we were to take the modulo $(x-1)$ of$\space$ $x^\alpha$ : $\alpha$ $\in$ $\mathbb{N}$,

$x^\alpha \mod (x-1)$ $\iff$ $(x \mod (x-1))^\alpha \mod (x-1)$

Since $x$ $-$ $(x-1)$ = $1$ (Given $p$):

$(x \mod (x-1))^\alpha \mod (x-1)$ $\equiv$ $[1]^\alpha \mod (x-1)$

We know that, $\forall$$\alpha$ , $1^\alpha = 1$

Hence, $[1]^\alpha\mod (x-1)$ $\equiv$ $[1] \mod (x-1)$

So,$\space$ $x^\alpha \mod (x-1)$ $\equiv$ $[1]$

Hence, $q$.

$p \implies q$.

$QED$.

Comment: Why do you need the explicit hypothesis that $x$,$(x-1)$ are coprime? Two consecutive positive integers $x$,$(x-1)$ are coprime automatically, aren't they?

Comment: Nobody else ever wrote $(C\equiv D \pmod E)^F$ before. What does it mean ?

Comment: Note that mathematicians don't use the concept of "taking the modulo", and don't use the notation "$a \, \mathrm{mod} \, b$". (I've written a bit about this at https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2072179/19345.)

Comment: @ruakh well, mathematicians don't _usually_ use $\operatorname{mod}$ as an infix operator $\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}\to\mathbb{N}$ like programmers do, but I daresay it's something everybody should understand without too much difficulty. If actually used in a consistent manned, that is. The problem with this question is that it seems to mix both notions of modulo in a very confusing way.

Comment: @leftaroundabout From here on, is it by convention that I should stick to one notion solely when working on something? I'm new to modular arithmetic so thanks for this.

Comment: I suggest that as ruakh said, you stick to $a \equiv b \mod c$ when adressing a maths audience. It's equivalent to what a programmer would write as $a \operatorname{mod} c == b \operatorname{mod} c$. Certainly don't write $x\operatorname{mod} y \Leftrightarrow P$ – if the “result” of mod is supposed to be a logical proposition, then you must specify _what_ you consider to hold modulo $y$.

Comment: It's called the [Polynomial Remainder Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_remainder_theorem)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

**Theorem:** (*reworded for  readability*) $ \ $ For any two positive integers $x$ and $\alpha$:
$$
x^\alpha - 1 \quad\mbox{ is divisible by }\quad x - 1.
$$

*Proof:* The difference $x^\alpha - 1$ can be factored as
$$
x^\alpha - 1 = (x-1)(x^{\alpha-1}+x^{\alpha-2}+\ldots+x+1).
$$
Q.E.D.

Comment: What is the need of writing two answers that are almost same ?

Comment: The above answer is purely mathematical, while the other addresses the historical question "who first proved it?". The functionality allowing one user to write multiple answers exists for a reason. Remember to [be nice and assume good intentions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/be-nice).

Comment: @A---B Comare these two statements: (A) "Difference of two squares always factors; difference of two cubes always factors in a similar manner; ditto for two biquadrates and higher powers." and (B) "All partial sums of a geometric series are integers iff all terms of such a series are integers." Do you honestly think (A) and (B) are the same? Granted, once we look at the formula for the sum of a geometric series, we begin to see a connection between (A) and (B) - but, *to most students, these are two different ideas*: (A) is about factoring a polynomial, while (B) is about summing a series.

Comment: Prove that $\sin x = \cos (\pi/2 - x) $ for $x \in [0,\pi/2]$. Now there are two ways to do this, one is to use the $\cos(A + B)$ and another is to observe a right angled triangle. Now by your logic both are different ideas and deserve two different answers right ?

Comment: The down votes under both of your answers are not by me, I can prove it.

Answer (score 21):

First, let me compliment you on your enthusiasm and curiosity and ability to care about proofs.

Now the bad news.  I'm afraid your theorem is trivial.

$$x= (x-1)+1 \equiv 1 \mod (x-1)\\
⇒ x^{\alpha}\equiv 1^{\alpha} \equiv 1\mod (x-1).$$

Answer (score 11):

**Who first proved it?**

[From Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series#Euclid): Book IX, Proposition 35 of Euclid's Elements expresses the partial sum of a geometric series in terms of members of the series. It is equivalent to the modern formula
$$
{x^\alpha-1\over x-1} = 1 + x + \ldots + x^{\alpha-1}.
$$
For a geometric series with integer terms, the partial sum $\displaystyle{x^\alpha-1\over x-1}$ is an integer. (Yet another restatement of your theorem.)

Answer (score 6):

Modulo $x-1$ clearly $x$ is $1$. So all the  powers of it  are also $1$.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't have a name, I think. It is a consequence of $$x\equiv y\pmod z\implies \forall n\in \mathbb N\;[\;x^n\equiv y^n\pmod z\;]$$ which is  shown by induction on $n$, by using the basic result that $$[x\equiv y \pmod z\land x'\equiv y' \pmod z]\implies xx'\equiv yy'\pmod z.$$